# Change button text color Android M

Tags: android, button, android-context, android-6.0-marshmallow

Ok, so i need to change two buttons´ text color after they have been clicked, and I´ve this:

```
manButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            manButton.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedGender));
            womanButton.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.unselectedGender));
        }
    });
```

But the method `getColor()` looks to be deprecated since Android M, and as my app is just for android lollipop and higher I need to solve this issue. I´ve been searching on the net and I´ve discovered that since Android M for getting a color from an xml you have to use: `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)` and I´ve tried it, but it says it can not resolve the symbol context, I´ve also tried changing `context` to `this`, as it is inside an Activity, but it gaves me this error:

```
 Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.view.View.OnClickListener', required: 'android.content.Context' 

getColor(android.content.Context,int) in ContextCompat cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener,int)
```

So, what should I do?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, what should I do?

Replace `this` with `WhateverYourActivityNameIs.this`, where `WhateverYourActivityNameIs` is whatever your activity class name is.